# Getting Data or content exactly as in excel using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

below is a portion of my method which causing the exception given below while getting the CellFormat instance. Please give any solution to extract the data as it is appear in the excel file.

```
   try
      {
         String dataStr = null;
         style = cell.getCellStyle();
         dataStr = style.getDataFormatString();
           CellFormat cf = CellFormat.getInstance(dataStr);
            if(cf != null)
                {
                  CellFormatResult result = cf.apply(cell); // -> this is the line which exactly giving exception.
                   if(!result.text.equals(EMPTY))
                        content = result.text;
                 }
                 }
                  catch(Exception e)
                 { 
                   System.out.println("row " + i + " column " + j);
                               e.printStackTrace();
                 }

 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellElapsedFormatter.<init>(CellElapsedFormatter.java:143)
            at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatType$4.formatter(CellFormatType.java:60)
            at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatPart.getFormatter(CellFormatPart.java:280)
            at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormatPart.<init>(CellFormatPart.java:172)
            at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormat.<init>(CellFormat.java:157)
            at org.apache.poi.ss.format.CellFormat.getInstance(CellFormat.java:133)
            at com.pawaa.conversion.exceltohtml.ExcelToHtmlConverter.printSheetContentImages(ExcelToHtmlConverter.java:572)
```

Actually when i debug i found the exception caused in the method in CellFormat class.

When cf.apply(cell) method invoked I got the NullPointerException because posNumFmt instance variable is null.

```
     private CellFormatPart getApplicableFormatPart(Object value) {

    if (value instanceof Number) {

        double val = ((Number) value).doubleValue();

        if (formatPartCount == 1) {
            if (!posNumFmt.hasCondition()
                    || (posNumFmt.hasCondition() && posNumFmt.applies(val))) {
                return posNumFmt;
            } else {
                return new CellFormatPart("General");
            }
        } else if (formatPartCount == 2) {
            if ((!posNumFmt.hasCondition() && val >= 0)
                    || (posNumFmt.hasCondition() && posNumFmt.applies(val))) {
                return posNumFmt;
            } else if (!negNumFmt.hasCondition()
                    || (negNumFmt.hasCondition() && negNumFmt.applies(val))) {
                return negNumFmt;
            } else {
                // Return ###...### (255 #s) to match Excel 2007 behaviour
                return new CellFormatPart(QUOTE + INVALID_VALUE_FOR_FORMAT + QUOTE);
            }
        } else {
            if ((!posNumFmt.hasCondition() && val > 0)
                    || (posNumFmt.hasCondition() && posNumFmt.applies(val))) {
                return posNumFmt;
            } else if ((!negNumFmt.hasCondition() && val < 0)
                    || (negNumFmt.hasCondition() && negNumFmt.applies(val))) {
                return negNumFmt;
            // Only the first two format parts can have conditions
            } else {
                return zeroNumFmt;
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("value must be a Number");
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the code at `CellElapsedFormatter.java:143`?

Comment: i edited code and mentioned the line which gives exception, sorry i forgot that, the ExcelToHtmlConverter class is mine remaining or all poi classes.

Comment: your actual issue is at `ExcelToHtmlConverter.java:572`. Does the above code contain that line? debug and see if either `style` or `style.getDataFormatString()` is `null`. I feel `style` is null.

Comment: What happens if you use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) instead?